# Excel: Running a macro in one sheet causes all references from different sheets to this worksheet to lose their reference and return a #REF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba6

I am currently working with multiple macros in my reporting model. The problem I encounter is the following:

The first macro that I use, copies all data in worksheet A (data is based on formula's from other sheets) and pastes the hard values into worksheet B. Next, I have a different worksheet C where some data refers and links to worksheet B.

When I run the macro in worksheet 1 again, the data might change in worksheet B, which is not a problem. However, the references in worksheet C give a `#REF!` instead of linking to the correct cell in worksheet B.

For example, when I use the following code in worksheet C:

```
=IF(LEFT('WorksheetB'!A1;3)="Yes"; 'WorksheetB'!B1; 0)
```

When I then run the macro, I get:

```
=IF(LEFT('WorksheetB'!#REF!;3)="Yes"; 'WorksheetB'!#REF!; 0)
```

Is there a way to keep the link to worksheet B, when a macro in worksheet A causes the data in worksheet B to change?

I tried everything. From locking the cells with F4 to creating another macro.

Here is the code of the Macro:

```
Sub X()
'
 If Worksheets("Checks").Range("C2").Value > 0.01 Then
        
        MsgBox "One or multiple checks is/are invalid"
        
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Sheets("Output for Exact").Select
    
    Myname = Filename & " " & Range("B2") & " " & "Q" & Sheets("General Input").Range("B5").Text & " EXPORTFILE "
    
    Columns("A:W").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accruals Previous Period").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Output for Exact").Select
    Columns("A:W").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accruals Previous Period").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Application.Run "Wisnullenrf3"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code, instead of just describing its effects.

Comment: try also showing the relevant parts of your code

Comment: I suspect your macro is changing or deleting ranges on WorksheetB. Please provide the code for your macro.

Comment: I included the code of the macro, thank you for the quick replies.

Comment: It would also help to qualify ranges with the sheet, instead of relying on the active sheet being the one you need. eg: `Worksheets("Accruals Previous PPeriod").Copy`.  (Also, [using  `.Select`, is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) or even needed usually).  You also copy columns A:W, but then don't do anything before copying again on a different sheet.  I **highly** recommend reading up on how to avoid using `.Select`, and how to properly qualify `Range` variables with the worksheet it should be on.

Comment: What does `Application.Run "Wisnullenrf3"` do?

Comment: The Wismullenrf3 makes sure that only cells larger than 0 are displayed

Comment: step through the code by pressing F8 once you are in the VBA IDE (CTRL-G to pop it out) and see at which statement those formulas begin showing the error

Comment: _"The Wismullenrf3 makes sure that only cells larger than 0 are displayed"_: 
what actions are taking place in Wismullenrf3 exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with cleaning up your code:

```
Sub X()
    If Worksheets("Checks").Range("C2").Value > 0.01 Then
            
            MsgBox "One or multiple checks is/are invalid"
            
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        'Sheets("Output for Exact").Select
        
        Myname = Filename & " " & Range("B2") & " " & "Q" & Sheets("General Input").Range("B5").Text & " EXPORTFILE "
        
        'Columns("A:W").Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Sheets("Accruals Previous Period").Select
        'Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("Output for Exact").Range("A:W").Copy
        Sheets("Accruals Previous Period").Range([the specfic cell where the PasteSpecial is to occur]).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Application.Run "Wisnullenrf3"
        
End Sub
```

The line where you're doing the PasteSpecial needs to have the specific cell where the PasteSpecial needs to happen.

You'll notice that I got rid of all the "Selects".  You don't have to select a cell to do something with it, just refer to the cell and do what needs to be done to it or get what you need to extract from it (Google "Object Oriented Programming" for more details).

Comment: To go on cleaning, I'd suggest making clear what workbooks (ActiveWorkbook, ThisWorkbook) the worksheets belong to
And proper use of indentation would also be useful